# Contract deployed successfully to Ganache via Truffle, fails to deploy on live network

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I basically followed [this Zeppelin crowdsale tutorial](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6), just changed the names of the contracts. I was able to successfully deploy on a local Ganache, but then when trying to deploy to the live ethereum network it fails on `invalid address`, apparently raised by migrating `1_initial_migration.js`, which looks like this:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

and Migrations.sol looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function Migrations() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot from the terminal where `truffle migration` fails:

[image]

How is it possible that I can deploy to Ganache but not to the live network? Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: apparently I'm running geth with `--light` modifier. can this be the reason?

Comment: that can be the reason, see: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41028/can-i-truffle-migrate-with-geth-light

Comment: Can you deploy to a testnet, for example Ropsten? You should anyway always first deploy to a testnet before live.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar issue I am able to resolve it after deleting JSON files from `/build/contracts`. Then I tried to redeploy the contract and it was done successfully.