# Can I truffle migrate with geth --light?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-migration

I get `invalid address` when I try to, I suspect --light doesn't enable deploys -- is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this issue

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/534

it's not possible to deploy with light sync mode.

The contract address in the transaction receipt will be null, which will cause the "invalid address" error.

There are also newer issues at github confirming that they also have the problem. E.g. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15366

There is someone working on a pull request for this.

> @ivica7 Hi, after investigation, the contract deploy correctly in
>   light mode. HOWEVER, it doesn't render correctly a contractAddress
>   after calling web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt, which is causing Truffle
>   to fail during the deployment.
>
> I'm working on a PR to fix this issue in truffle with a work-around.
>   Will keep you posted.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed in 1.8